# Show different group header and footer per section

Tags: reporting-services, group-by, ssrs-2008

Can anyone tell me how to show SSRS group header and footer in SSRS 2008R2? The idea is to have an approach like in Crystal Reports, where we can add a group header/footer and do our own design in that section on every page based on page break functionality.

Does anyone know an approach for this in SSRS? I should be able to show my own design/controls/dataset fields group header area, and be able to see it on every page based on the page break by group. Would also appreciate if you can share any video or tutorial related to the approach.

Below is my scenario and the issues:

[image: intended functionality]

Answer (score 0):

First off, you can't really do much in Page Header and Footer in SSRS 2008, this will not be flexible enough for these requirements.

Probably the best workaround then to create multiple sections is to split the main report into several [subreports](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220581%28v=sql.100%29.aspx). Each subreport can have it's own "starting area" with images, textboxes, aggregate info: whatever you'd like in your "header". In the main report you could set up [page breaks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207058.aspx) to make sure each "section" (subreport) appears on a new page.

One downside to this approach, as mentioned in the first bit of this answer: you can't repeat the header on each page, because Page Header and Footer are ignored for subreports.