# Placeholder value from a group field

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, placeholder, reportbuilder3.0

I have a report where I did grouping by currency, and also I have added total by currency, so if I generate my report, the data related to each currency are sorted, and after each Currency Type set of rows I have the total of the currency

The hearder info (Textbox. and PlaceHolder values) are repeated to each currency

Also when I export to excel, I have adjusted the report to save the results of each currency on a different sheet, and having the sheet name renamed to Currency

My Problem is that in the header of the report I have a PlaceHolder that should display the currency.
However in the PlaceHolder expression, it only allow me to enter "=First(Fields!Currency1.Value, "dataSet")".

But when I generate the report it only shows the first currency "AED" even for data and sheets of other currency

How can I display the correct currency same as I did in excel sheet name for a placeholder expression?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did find a solution:

1. Insert a Header in the report.
2. Drag Currency field from dataset into the header.
3. Edit the expression
4. Change "=First(Fields!Currency1.Value, "dataSet")" into "=First(ReportItems!Currency1.Value)"

Also note that the above only works only for the header, it doesnt work in a placeholder expression in a textbox

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I have bad news for you. You can't access the datasets in any way other than using functions such as `First` in the page header in SSRS, and there is no way to let the header "respond" to what's going on in the body.

Perhaps my suggestion in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12767211/419956) can help you out as well. This comes down to not using a header but "faking" a header in the body. Not pretty, but it may work for your scenario.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback.. Can you tell me what are the functions i can use other than First??
Also i have tried to insert another table and provide it one single value "Currency", i tried to modify the properties same as the original in order to have both tables combined: first table show only the currency and the second show the rest of report, but i didnt succeed, when i export to excel it shows me the results of currency table splitted into sheet by currency, and then the original table splitted into sheet, i need them both to be splitted together.. any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Oh, you are so close! You set yourself up for success when you made the page name dependent on the currency name.

Don't use anything from your dataset directly, use the information from the dataset you are already passing to your report structure. You are already putting the currency name where your header can find it by making it the page name.

```
=Globals!PageName
```

as the expression for your placeholder.